# Pyspark, help changing this code to subtract different rows

Tags: pyspark

I want to subtract the current value2 row from the previous value1 row, when week > 1

here is my data:
'''

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 0, 5),
    (3, 0, 10),
    (4, 0, 20),
    (5, 0, 30),
    (6, 0, 40)
]
columns = ["week", "value1", "value2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

'''

here is the code:

```
w=Window.orderBy("week")
                          
df2 = df.withColumn('value1',
                    f.when((f.col('week') > 1),
                           f.sum(f.lag(df['value1']).over(w) - df['value2']).over(w)
                          ).otherwise(
                        f.col('value1')
                    )
                   )
```

the current code subtracts the previous row value 1 form the current value2 row but I want to swicht it to subtracting the current value2 row from previous value1 row.

the answer should look like this:

```
+----+------+------+
|week|value1|value2|
+----+------+------+
|1   |1     |1     |
|2   |4     |5     |
|3   |6     |10    |
|4   |14    |20    |
|5   |16    |30    |
|6   |24    |40    |
+----+------+------+
```

Thank you to everyone who helps here, I appreciate you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Use the `row_number` function to identify even or odd rows, multiply them by `-1`, and then apply a `abs(running sum)` to that column to get your desired output.

```
df.
withColumn(
    "value1", 
    expr("""
        ABS(
            CASE WHEN week > 1 THEN 
                SUM(
                    CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY week) % 2 == 0) THEN 
                        -1 * value2 
                    ELSE 
                        value2 
                    END
                ) OVER(ORDER BY week)
            ELSE 
                value1 
            END
        )
    """)
).show(False)
```

```
+----+------+------+
|week|value1|value2|
+----+------+------+
|1   |1     |1     |
|2   |4     |5     |
|3   |6     |10    |
|4   |14    |20    |
|5   |16    |30    |
|6   |24    |40    |
+----+------+------+
```